# shortcut of the current directory path when vsplit/split

Tags: split, variables, path

I very often need to open files through `vsplit/split`. Very often I want to open files in the same directory. Still, I must pass their paths to `vsplit/split`.

```
:vsplit @/siblingfile.txt
```

`@` is an alias equal to the path of the current file (that exists only in my imagination of course but you got the idea :) ).

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

```
--> vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:00:18)
```

> :echo has('cmdline_compl') displays 1

Comment: Not what you're asking for, but related: `:Vex` and `:Sex`

Comment: As long as autocomplete does not work for me with `%:h/`, your solution is faster thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `%:h/`

NB: you can tab-complete at any point after the `:h`.

Comment: thanks, but the autocomplete does not work at all, neither does `CTRL-d`

Comment: You'll need to make sure your version of vim supports command-line expansion (`:echo has('cmdline_compl')` shall display 1). See `:h cmdline-completion` regarding the various options vim looks at.

Answer (score 2):

As Luc indicated, you can type: `:vsplit %:h` then `<Tab>`.

---

I use this mapping to transform `%%` into the current directory from the command line:

```
cnoremap <expr> %% getcmdtype() ==# ':' ? fnameescape(expand('%:h')) . '/' : '%%'
```

Usage: `:e %%`

- `:help c_%` (`%` replaced with the current file name)
- `:help %:h` (`%:h` to get the head of the file name, aka last part removed)

Comment: Thanks, but the autocomplete does not work at all, neither does `CTRL-d`

Comment: Try `:set nocompatible` but compatibility mode should already be disabled if you use a vimrc file.

Comment: Still not work :/

Comment: Strange, should be the fix if you see `^I` when pressing `<Tab>`. You don't even need auto completion, just `:e %:h` and enter to open the current directory.

Comment: pressing `<Tab>` has no effect and `<CTRL-D>-d` supposed to show the content of a directory does as if there is nothing